# Dynamic tabulator size for CSV files in VS Code

Tags: csv, visual-studio-code

I have a tab-separated CSV/TSV file and I want to edit it in VS Code.

**Sample:**

```
row1    cell1   cell2   cell3   cell4
row2    lorem ipsum dolor   sit amet
```

and I want to view them column-aligned in such a way, that VS Code dynamically changes the rendering size of each tab character. I remember using an extension to do exactly that a couple of years ago, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

The only extensions I can find are ones that...
a) ...pad each cell with spaces on command (e.g. RainbowCSV). **I don't want this, as I can't have trailing whitespace in the data.**
b) ...render the CSV in a separate, Excel-like table editor. **I don't want this either, as it is very cumbersome and prevents me from using other text editing tools avialble in VS Code.**

Is there any such extension?

**TL;DR:** I'm searching for a VS Code extension that renders a CSV/TSV *as text* without inserting any extra characters.

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77674759/11107541. see if any of the answers are useful to you